# Update iframe in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, iframe

I'm trying to use AngularJS to update my iframe whenever a query is made. For example, a query is made, then the embed link is retrieved from the database. That link is then used in the iframe. The title and the video are then displayed. This part works for me so far. After that first query though, when I make another query, the iframe does not update, but the title does, so I know that the query is working fine, but there's something wrong with the iframe. How do I update my iframe?

If I do a search that returns one value followed by a search that has multiple results and then another search with a single result, the iframe does change. It changes from the second div to the first div and then back to the second div. So if there's a way to change the div between single searches, the second div can update. Does anyone know how I can do this?

```
<div ng-if="things.length>1">
   <div ng-repeat="thing in things">
     <li><a <a href="{{ thing.name }}">{{ thing.name }} </a></li>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="things.length==1" class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
   <h1> {{ things[0].name }} </h1>
   <iframe width="560" height="315" ng-src="{{ things[0].embed }}" frameborder="0"allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

**Edit**
This is my control.js.

```
var coreControl = angular.module('myCore', []);

function mainController ($scope, $http, $sce) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.things   = [];

    $http.get('/*')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.things = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });

    $scope.search = function() {
        $http.post('*', $scope.formData)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.formData = {};
                $scope.things    = data;
                $scope.things[0].embed = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.things[0].embed);

                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };
    }
```

**Another update: Resolved**

Comment: Champion for figuring that out! Thanks for posting the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after randomly finding out that my code works in Firefox, but not Chrome, I did some searching. I found that the Facebook Disconnect plugin was blocking my iframes from rendering. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/e3eRJy3vXSM

Answer (score 1):

I've made a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZQVAt2rSFzy3bklal4OB?p=preview) that changes the first object in `things` on a button click and it seems to update the iFrame like expected.

Check your console and see if there is an error message when you try load the other src. Some sites like google set `X-Frame-Options` so that the site can't be accessed by your iFrame.

Comment: Nope. No error messages. I just updated my original post with my control.js code. $scope.things = data is definitely getting a new result from the database because the title is updating, and the embed link is also updating. I don't know why the iframe does not update though.

Comment: Also, your plunker code only changes the frame once. Why is that? Shouldn't it be able to change back to the first frame if I click the button again?

Comment: It only changes the iFrame once 'cause that's how I programmed it...just to test. When you 'inspect element' of the iFrame what is the value of `src`? Is it what you expect? The new value?

Comment: When I inspect element of the iframe before and after, the value of src remains the same.

Comment: Hmmm...that's weird..but you said `things[0].name` changes?

Comment: yeah, that changes, but the iframe remains the same. I have no idea why. I tried adding this to control.js
document.getElementById('viddy').src = document.getElementById('viddy').src;
but this didn't work either.

Comment: So now I'm trying to debug through you (unless you can put a Plunker together)...in the `.success` above `console.log(data);` can you see what the value of `things[0].embed` is (`console.log($scope.things[0].embed);`)

Comment: Yeah, I can see the value of things[0].embed, not with console.log(), but if I place it in the html, it shows up.

Comment: I'm trying to make a plunker, but I don't know how to simulate the database so I can replicate querying for different values....

Comment: Yer..it becomes a lot of effort...here's another [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CKkOrEZcdSh3XGiK8mVk?p=preview) I made to test that it has nothing to do with the `.success` or `.then` in my case.

Comment: I've tried my all to try and get it not to work on my end...but no luck...just one last thing...can you copy and paste exactly what `console.log(data);` shows.

Comment: Ok....I just tested my code in Firefox and everything works perfectly. Before I was only testing in Chrome. I'm really confused??? Do you know what the problem might be?